# Two lines segment intersection step by step

Tags: geometry, line-intersection

I am studying algorithm and math and I came up to "Intersection of two line segment". I searched a good code and explanation about it but with no luck I didn't understand how it works step by step. I read this page and @Gareth explained it well [Here's the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563198/how-do-you-detect-where-two-line-segments-intersect) . I am very confused. I Have a example like this one `p=(11,11), r=(-12,-12), q=(0,0), s=(0,10)`. My question is how will I apply it to @gareth's expanation. :-(, I am not really good in math so for now I need help.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you guys. Hope there is someone would help me understand this.

Comment: If you want another source, I included a detailed explanation in my book, Section7.2  Segment-Segment Intersection:  [*Computational Geometry in C*](http://cs.smith.edu/~orourke/books/compgeom.html).